# H4 visa expiry before reach USA

Tags: h4-visa

My spouse is currently holding H1B and is going to expire in coming Nov 30th. And have plan to apply extension along with H4 visa.

I am currently holding H4 and staying in outside USA.

My question is to avoid immigration issues/questions, how many days earlier I should be land in USA before 30th NOV and too apply for extension too.

And what type of questions I can face while entering USA immigration.

Regards,
SN

Comment: As far as I understand it, you can arrive with your H-4 visa on any day up to and including 30 Nov.  If you wait until after 30 Nov, you will need to apply for a new visa, but you'll have to do that anyway the next time you leave the US after that date in order to return subsequently.  There's little point in going to the US before 30 Nov just for the sake of using the visa.